# tab_stat_cpct not giving the required result

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table as shown in picture for multi response data with list of banner . i have tried the below way but didn't worked.

```
library(expss)
mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars1$dd <- ifelse(mtcars1$gear == 4,1,NA)
mtcars1$ff <- ifelse(mtcars1$gear == 5,1,NA)

mtcars1$dd<-factor(mtcars1$dd, levels=c(1), labels=c("Local"))
mtcars1$ff<-factor(mtcars1$ff, levels=c(1), labels=c("Regional"))

mtcars1$vs<-factor(mtcars1$vs, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Male","female"))
mtcars1$am<-factor(mtcars1$am, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Male","female"))

mk <- with(mtcars1,list(total(),dd,ff))

T1 <- mtcars1 %>%
  tab_cells(vs,am) %>%
  tab_cols(mk) %>%
  tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
  tab_pivot() %>%
  split_table_to_df()
```

required out look like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use dichotomy encoding, you need to set variable labels rather than value labels. And you should to specify columns from which consists mutiple response set. For dichotomy, it is `mdset` function:

```
library(expss)
data(mtcars)
mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars1$dd <- ifelse(mtcars1$gear == 4,1,NA)
mtcars1$ff <- ifelse(mtcars1$gear == 5,1,NA)

mtcars1$dd<-set_var_lab(mtcars1$dd, "Local")
mtcars1$ff<-set_var_lab(mtcars1$ff, "Regional")

mtcars1$vs<-factor(mtcars1$vs, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Male","female"))
mtcars1$am<-factor(mtcars1$am, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Male","female"))

mk <- with(mtcars1,list(total(),mdset(dd, ff)))

T1 <- mtcars1 %>%
    tab_cells(vs,am) %>%
    tab_cols(mk) %>%
    tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
    tab_pivot() %>%
    split_table_to_df()
```

Comment: rather than changing banner can i apply the mdset in tab_cols(mk)...??? and its still not giving the required output

Comment: @samrr_tr I don't really understand your deisred output. How do you expect "male" and "female" in header if you explicity set labels as "regional" and "local"?

Comment: My bad, Yes its "Local" and "regional" in place of dd and ff in place of headers

Comment: i have updated the required output